# Pandas merge result missing rows when joining on strings

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have a data set that I've been cleaning and to clean it I needed to put it into  a pivot table to summarize some of the data. I'm now putting it back into a dataframe so that I can merge it with some other dataframes. df1 looks something like this:

```
    Count   Region              Period      ACV  PRJ
    167     REMAINING US WEST   3/3/2018    5    57
    168     REMAINING US WEST   3/31/2018   10   83
    169     SAN FRANCISCO       1/13/2018   99   76
    170     SAN FRANCISCO       1/20/2018   34   21
```

df2 looks something like this:

```
Count  MKTcode  Region
11     RSMR0    REMAINING US SOUTH
12     RWMR0    REMAINING US WEST
13     SFR00    SAN FRANCISCO
```

I've tried merging them with this code:

```
df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='Region', how='inner')
```

but for some reason pandas is not interpreting the Region columns as the same data and the merge is turning up NaN data in the MKTcode column and it seems to be appending df2 to df1, like this:

```
Count  Region             Period    ACV             PRJ         MKTcode
193 WASHINGTON, D.C.    3/3/2018    36               38             NaN
194 WASHINGTON, D.C.    3/31/2018   12                3             NaN
195 ATLANTA              NaN        NaN             NaN           ATMR0
196 BOSTON               NaN        NaN             NaN           B2MRN
```

I've tried inner and outer joins, but the real problem seems to be that pandas is interpreting the Region column of each dataframe as different elements.
The MKTcode column and Region column in df2 has only 12 observations and each observation occurs only once, whereas df1 has several repeating instances in the Region column (multiples of the same city). Is there a way where I can just create a list of the 12 MKTcodes that I need and perform a merge where it matches with each region that I designate? Like a one to many match?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When a merge isn't working as expected, the first thing to do is look at the offending columns.

**The biggest culprit in most cases is trailing/leading whitespaces**. These are usually introduced when DataFrames are incorrectly read from files.

Try getting rid of extra whitespace characters by stripping them out. Assuming you need to join on the "Region" column, use

```
for df in (df1, df2):
    # Strip the column(s) you're planning to join with
    df['Region'] = df['Region'].str.strip()
```

Now, merging should work as expected,

```
pd.merge(df1, df2, on='Region', how='inner')

   Count_x             Region     Period  ACV  PRJ  Count_y MKTcode
0      167  REMAINING US WEST   3/3/2018    5   57       12   RWMR0
1      168  REMAINING US WEST  3/31/2018   10   83       12   RWMR0
2      169      SAN FRANCISCO  1/13/2018   99   76       13   SFR00
3      170      SAN FRANCISCO  1/20/2018   34   21       13   SFR00
```

---

Another possibility if you're still getting NaNs, could be because of a **difference in whitespace characters *between* words**. For example, `'REMAINING  US  WEST'` will not compare as equal with `'REMAINING US WEST'`.

This time, the fix is to use `str.replace`:

```
for df in (df1, df2):
    df['Region'] = df['Region'].str.replace(r'\s+', ' ')
```

Comment: You're 100% right! I'll be marking your answer as correct once it allows me too. I'll have to watch for that in the future. Thank you!

Comment: You can also (probably) do something generic like: `df1.select_dtypes(object).applymap(str.strip).ne(df1.select_dtypes(object))` to get a mask for those items

Comment: @JonClements Neat, thanks! By the way, any idea whether `select_dtypes` returns a view or a fresh copy of the data?

Comment: My apologies, but what's a mask?

Comment: @CharlesD It's a dataframe of bool values, you can use it to index into `df`, and similar stuff (post mortem debugging).

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I think it's a copy :( (that's if `df1.select_dtypes(object)._is_view` is anything to go by... I'm sure that's not the right way to do that anyway... brain's tired :) (think it's something like `values.base is... other.values.base` or something